# Как обратиться к библиотеке в AMD модуле?

Tags: javascript, зависимости, модульность

Есть модуль:

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap'] ,function ($, bootstrap) {

});
```

В другом файле инициированы модули:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'scripts',
paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-3.2.1.min',
    bootstrap: '../libs/bootstrap/dist/js/boostrap.min.js'
    }
});
```

Предположим, я хочу вызвать бутстраповскую функцию $('..').carousel(). Как мне обратиться к этой функции в модуле, используя зависимость?